# Calendar view is displaying one month before

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

I am using the Material Calendar View of gitHub. Now I am doing my on month change listener in the calendar view. When I change the month it is displaying the previous month. For example for November its showing October and in February its showing January. Moreover, when I change to January or December the following error will appear:

```
  org.threeten.bp.DateTimeException: Invalid value for MonthOfYear: 0
```

my code is

```
   materialCalendarView.setOnMonthChangedListener(new OnMonthChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMonthChanged(MaterialCalendarView widget, CalendarDay date) {


          Month month = Month.of(date.getMonth());


          weekoffs.setText(month.toString());


        }
    });
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I see at least 3 Material Calendar View libraries on GitHub. Which one?

Comment: com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.5.0 this only

Comment: Originally month array index started from 0 so you need to increment +1 and get the expected result

Comment: That library sets the month from 0-11, while the CalendarDay and Month objects use 1-12. The library is broken.

Answer (score 2):

It has already been mentioned in the comments by Zahoor Saleem and TheWanderer, but it deserves to be an answer: the month number you get from a `CalendarDay` is “0-based”, that is, 0 for January, etc., through 11 for December. So if you pick a date in October, for example, you get 9, which `Month` quite naturally understand as September. One month before, as you observed.

The trivial solution is to add 1:

```
      // getMonth() is 0-based, so add 1
      Month month = Month.of(date.getMonth() + 1);
```

It’s not very nice. If you prefer, there is an alternative:

```
      // getMonth() is 0-based, so use as index into the (0-based) array of Months
      Month month = Month.values()[date.getMonth()];
```